# I want to select my database's region to Seoul, but it can't

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use firebase Realtime Database. So, I create realtime database in my project. but, there's no region in my region, Seoul (cuz, I'm living in Seoul, Republic of korea). How can I select my region to seoul? Sorry if my English is awkward.
[my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTarq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is currently available in these [locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations):

| Location name | Actual location |
| --- | --- |
| us-central1 | Iowa |
| europe-west1 | Belgium |
| asia-southeast1 | Singapore |

There is no location in Korea. So you will either have to use one of the existing locations, or look for a [database that *is* available in Seoul, Korea](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+database+in+seoul) - such as [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-r).

Comment: oh very thanks! I should select between those regions.